# confusion matrix and Jaccard index computation in O(n) for cluster comparison

Tags: clustering, computational-statistics, jaccard-similarity

**My problem:**
I have two clustering (or partitions) of a set of numbers $\{1,...,n\}$, each with $k$ cluster (or subsets), that i have to compare and, to do that, i'd like to try some different indexes like Jaccard, Mirkin and the Variation of Information, so i need to compute a confusion matrix. Given that labels are random in ***1,...,k***, a naive implementation to compute a confusion matrix like this

[image]

would be to compute for every $i,j \in [1,...,k]$ the number of co-clustered pairs of elements, but this algorithm is $O(k^2) $

I've read a few papers where the authors say that confusion matrix can be calculated in $O(n)$. In [Integrating Microarray Data by Consensus Clustering](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~filkov/papers/ictai03.pdf), for example, they choose a  *symmetric difference distance distance* that they can compute from $b$ and $c$ values of a cunfusion matrix, values that can be computed in $O(n)$ time. How can they do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have $O(1)$ lookups of cluster memberships, you can iterate of all objects, query both cluster memberships, and tabulate this in a $k^2$ matrix (counting the frequency of object being in cluster $i$ resp. $j$). This part is $O(n)$.
From this $k\times k$ matrix, you can efficiently compute the $2 \times 2$ "pair confusion" matrix. This part is $O(k^2)$.

The total algorithm thus is $O(n\cdot k^2)$ and if we assume $k^2\ll n$ to be neglibile then we have $O(n)$.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not true in my case that $k^2<<n$, cause i'm solving a vehicle routing problem and for 200 customers i can have 18-20 vehicles (subsets). But, if I keep a **co-clustered** counter , every time i update a cell during the $O(n)$ phase i update my $co-clustered$ counter (if the cell value is 3, when add an element i have 3 new co-clustred pairs) , so i can avoid the $O(k^2)$ phase. Am i wrong?

Comment: If $n=200$, **asymptotic** complexity is completely irrelevant. $1000\cdot n > n^2$ if $n=200$! But with $n=200$, anything should be only a few ms. So don't attempt to solve a problem that you do not have.

Comment: yes, you'right. But i've implemented it in a genetic algorithm where the distance/similarity function is called tens of thousands of times. so computation time actually changes quite a lot!

Comment: Yes, but not the *asymptotic* runtime. Again, $1000\cdot n > n^2$. A *fast quadratic* algorithm can outperform a linear algorithm on tiny data sets, in particular when called millions of times. That is why you sort *tiny* data sets with insertion sort (which is $O(n^2)$) and *not* heap sort (which is $O(n \log n)$ but has a much larger constant factor). Therefore, **benchmark** and **profile** your code.

Comment: Ok, now i understand! thank you very much for your patience!